# Out of memory on Android App on scrolling list with images

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an Android App. activity load two bitmaps for each row. app is crashing after few scroll up and down because of **Out Of Memory**

Exception is

```
   01-04 12:58:45.328: E/dalvikvm-heap(30264): Out of memory on a 307216-byte allocation.
   01-04 12:58:45.328: I/dalvikvm(30264): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
   01-04 12:58:45.328: I/dalvikvm(30264):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c40460 self=0xb3ca38
   01-04 12:58:45.328: I/dalvikvm(30264):   | sysTid=30264 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074541800
   01-04 12:58:45.328: I/dalvikvm(30264):   | schedstat=( 14267042000 1117190000 14168 )    utm=1325 stm=101 core=1
   01-04 12:58:45.328: I/dalvikvm(30264):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
```

Its my main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/DefaultMargin" 
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/DefaultMargin" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCourseEmpty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty_course_list_label"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListView item is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/DefaultMargin"
        android:layout_weight="0.65" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coursestatelogo"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/DefaultMargin"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="right" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/courselabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/HalfMargin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/HalfMargin"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/courselogo"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Array Adapter Code:

```
public class CourseArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CourseData>{

    private final Context context;
    private final CourseData[] values;

    public CourseArrayAdapter(Context context, CourseData[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_course_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_course_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.courselabel);
        textView.setText(Farsi.Convert(values[position].Name));


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.courselogo);


        ImageView imageViewstate = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.coursestatelogo);




        switch (values[position].State){
            case NotStarted :
                if (values[position].Downloaded)
                    imageViewstate.setImageResource(R.drawable.downloaded);
                else
                    imageViewstate.setImageResource(R.drawable.download);
                break;
            case InProgress :
                imageViewstate.setImageResource(R.drawable.lesson);
                break;
            case Certified :
                imageViewstate.setImageResource(R.drawable.certificate);
                break;
        }

        return rowView;
    }
```

}

Comment: try using convertview in getView() adapter.. It may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check contvertView is null or not.

```
View rowView;
if (convertView== null) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_course_item, parent, false);
}else
 rowView = convertView;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether you can reuse the incoming view, before inflating a new one.

```
View rowView;

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ...;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(...);
} else
    rowView = convertView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple stuff i would suggest you:

1. Use row-views recycle
2. Read this article: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html, it will shows you how display images efficiently.